# MS SAPI sdk equivalent on OSX

Tags: macos, speech-recognition, sapi, phonetics

I'm looking for an SDK that would allow me to have speech recognition on a OSX application.

I already have a working code for windows using sapi, to get speech recognition info from an audio file, and i would like to see how to do this in osx since something like SAPI is not available.

Thanks!

Comment: It’d help if you stated what exactly do you need. For example, would `NSSpeechRecognizer` be enough?

Answer (score 1):

The OS X equivalent is the Speech Recognition service:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/speech/Articles/RecognizeSpeech.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002081-BCIHEBFH

Note that the Speech Recognition service is limited to listening for predefined command phrases. It cannot be used for dictation.