# OS X Yosemite (10.10) API for continuous speech recognition

Tags: speech-recognition, osx-yosemite, dictation

OSX has now had continuous speech recognition built in for several versions.

It is remarkably good now.

Does OSX 10.10 have an API for this continuous speech recognition engine?

Googling tells me that circa 2009 there was only NSSpeechRecogniser ([MS SAPI sdk equivalent on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073695/ms-sapi-sdk-equivalent-on-osx))

Can anyone confirm whether this is still the case?

I'm asking because I am looking at building my own integrated UI, which would be a mix of Leap controller and speech input.

If only I could use OSX's engine, this would be fantastic. Otherwise I don't think I have any other good/viable option.